# Commonsware CWAC switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to implement the Commonsware CWAC-Camera and I am running into an issue incorporating it into an existing fragment.

I am getting an issue where I cannot use .add or .replace and it wants me to change CameraFragment to Fragment.

ERROR:

> The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, CameraFragment, String)

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


 import java.io.File;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment;




public void takePicture() {

    CameraFragment f = new CameraFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contentFragment, f, TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();
}
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Here is the entire fragment.

```
public class FeedActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ImageButton btnCamera, btnGallery;
    private final String TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT = "camera_fragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_feed, container, false);

        btnCamera = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Camera);
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnGallery = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Gallery);
        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_Camera:
        Log.e("CAMERA", "CAMERA BUTTON PRESSED");
            //takePicture();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_Gallery:
            Log.e("Gallery", "GALLERY BUTTON PRESSED");
            break;

        }

    }

    public void takePicture() {

        CameraFragment f = new CameraFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.contentFragment, f, TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I cannot use .add or .replace and it wants me to change CameraFragment to Fragment" -- I do not know what you mean by this. Please provide the exact message and indicate what is giving you the message (an IDE? LogCat? something else?) If I had to guess, you have the wrong imports and are trying to mix the fragments backport with native API Level 11+ fragments, but that's just a guess.

Comment: The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, CameraFragment, String)

Comment: I just included the error. The quick fix read "change f to Fragment". My apologies.

Comment: Please edit your question to paste in the full list of `import` statements for this Java source file. My guess was correct, and you are mixing some fragments backport classes with the API Level 11+ fragments classes, but without the imports, I cannot tell you precisely what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and:

```
import com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment;
```

are incompatible. You need to decide if you want to use the fragments backport from the Android Support package or if you want to use native API Level 11+ fragments. And you need to modify your entire activity to support your choice (e.g., inherit from `FragmentActivity` if you are using the backport).

If you want to use the backport, you will need to use the `camera-v9` library and import `com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment`, though this also uses ActionBarSherlock. If you want the backport of fragments but not ActionBarSherlock, you will need to fork one of my `CameraFragment` implementations to support that combination.

Answer (score 0):

**Issues**

I would like to show you my way to solve the `CameraFragment` incompatibility issue.  My app use V4 Support Library (somehow I don't know why) but no ActionBarSherlock.  Because my target platform is V11 and above (yes, not supporting 2.3 and below).

- `com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment` -> not compatible with V4 Support Library, hence not compatible with our V4 FragmentActivity and other fragments.
- `com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment` -> won't work because I don't have ActionBarSherlock.

**Common Solution**

Usually, the app will have lots of fragments and some with list or grid.  They all share some common functions.  We might use a static utils class but it might create more problems than it solved.  For example, it will require passing `this` fragment pointer in function calls.  End up we have these:

```
java.lang.Object
↳ android.support.v4.app.Fragment
  ↳ com.example.app.BaseFragment           <- with common functions

java.lang.Object
↳ android.app.Fragment
  ↳ android.app.ListFragment
    ↳ com.example.app.BaseListFragment     <- with common functions

java.lang.Object
↳ android.app.Fragment
  ↳ com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment
    ↳ com.example.app.BaseCameraFragment   <- with common functions
```

**Problems**

- The middle class fragments may extends from different fragment: original or V4 support library.
- There are multiple copies of common functions, inside those Base...Fragment classes.  Maintenance is difficult and time wasting.

However, I notice somethings about these fragments we extended from:

1. they are well-completed, and very unlikely to change.
2. they are mostly open sourced.
3. they usually won't care whether their parent is original or V4 support - they work on their own.

**Solution**

So, instead of extending from them, we can either (a) change their parent class, or (b) clone them and extends from whichever fragment we like:

```
java.lang.Object
↳ android.support.v4.app.Fragment
  ↳ com.example.app.BaseFragment           <- with common functions
    ↳ com.example.app.BaseListFragment     
      // with content from android.app.ListFragment
    ↳ com.example.app.BaseCameraFragment
      // with content from com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment
```

(please note, we still have to follow the GNU license where applicable)

Usually, I prefer not to alter their source code, so I can easily update to latest version when available.  So, I will keep the original inside the app and use method b.  The only work is to diff their version with my clones.

**Benefits**

1. maintain one fragment with common functions.
2. resolve base type incompatibility.
3. easy to change the base-base fragment type.
4. (for CWAC) I can avoid `camera-v9` which requires ActionBarSherlock, and I have all fragments extends from v4 fragment.

Enjoy~

Comment: Oh regarding why I use v4 fragment even the min-target is Android 4.0+: one day, my teammate told me that in some early version (such as 4.0), there are problems with their built-in fragment.  It is wiser to use v4 support library.  So that the app will be using the bug-fixed version of fragment and FragmentActivity.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  As I see no harm in using V4 library, so......